# Using a subquery in an aggregate expression

Tags: t-sql

Instead of this:

```
SELECT Customer,SUM(OrderPrice) FROM Orders
GROUP BY Customer
```

How do I get something like above but by producing a COUNT from a subquery.

```
SELECT Customer,Count(select * from Orders where o.idUser = u.idUser) FROM Orders o 
inner join Users u on u.idOrder = o.idOrder
GROUP BY Customer
```

thx

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you want?. You want to obtain the `SUM` of `OrderPrice` **and** a `COUNT`?, or do you want to get a `SUM` **using** a `COUNT`?...and why are you joining with another table?.

Comment: I want the number (count) of orders of orders - the join's there to help with the next problem i have to solve. And now i'm unsure it's appropriate. I'll probably have to edit the OP to clarify. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do, I see no need to include Orders in the Topquery:

```
SELECT u.Customer, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders o WHERE o.idUser = u.idUser)
FROM Users u
```

Comment: I believe, `Customer` is a column in `Orders`, not in `Users`.